# Ошибка синтаксиса C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

> Cs.(9,38): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol "=".

Всё перепробовал, не получается решить.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Moveplayer : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform player;

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 MousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        player.position = new Vector2 = (MousePos.x. player.position.y);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
player.position = new Vector2(MousePos.x, MousPos.y);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-ctor.html